# How can I break a loop in Python/selenium when text on a page is not found?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a loop that keeps going until the partial link text "Ticket Request" is no longer found on the page.  I've looked into options, but I don't know how to actually check whether or not a link is found.

Here is the basic idea of the loop I'm creating.  I have a for loop with a high limit temporarily until I find a better solution.

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.get('https://www.webpage.com')
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Ticket Request'))
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Requesting a Restricted Lead').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you use a try/catch

```
try:
  wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Ticket Request'))
except: 
  print "Did not find the element, I can now do what I want"
  #break #if you really want to break out of something
```

After waiting for 30 seconds if the driver cannot find the link "Ticket Request", it will print and break out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break a loop, use the `break` keyword.

So, for example:

```
for i in range(100):
   ... # do stuff
   if some_condition:
       break
```

Comment: I know that, but I don't know how to specifically break if text in a webpage isn't found.